# Incompatible types List and Page

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I am developing a webapp using JHipster that manages payments and wanted to filter the payments that a user can see so he can only see his payments. To do this I was following the [blog tutorial](https://youtu.be/ZGF4gEM4FuA?t=811) from Matt Raible on Youtube. He uses findByUserIsCurrentUser() which is generated by JHipster.

```
List<Blog> blogs = blogRepository.findByUserIsCurrentUser();
```

When I went to make the same change in my project I found the type that I must return is a Page and I get an incompatible type error, here is my method:

```
public Page<Payment> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("Request to get all Payments");
    Page<Payment> result = paymentRepository.findByUserIsCurrentUser();
    return result;
}
```

If I change the findAll(pageable) for findByUserIsCurrentUser() which is declared in the PaymentRepository as follows

```
public interface PaymentRepository extends JpaRepository<Payment,Long> {
    @Query("select payment from Payment payment where payment.user.login = ?#{principal.username}")
    List<Payment> findByUserIsCurrentUser();
}
```

I get the following error:

[image: Error]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this in two ways. This is assuming you are using a service, if not it's still pretty similar:

**Method 1:** If you want your service to return ALL payments for the current user, then you need to modify your service and probably your resource to handle a list instead of a page:

```
public List<Payment> findAll() {
    log.debug("Request to get all Payments");
    List<Payment> result = paymentRepository.findByUserIsCurrentUser();
    return result;
}
```

And in your resource:

```
public List<Payment> getAllPayments() {
    log.debug("REST request to get all Payments");
    List<Payment> payments = paymentService.findAll();
    return payments;
}
```

Alternatively, you can change `"pagination": "pagination"` to `"pagination": "no"` in `.jhipster/Payment.json` and rerun the generator. This will regenerate the service, resource and repository without pagination.

**Method 2:** If you want your service to be paginated, you need to change your repository method to accept the `Pageable` object, and return a page:

```
public interface PaymentRepository extends JpaRepository<Payment,Long> {
    @Query("select payment from Payment payment where payment.user.login = ?#{principal.username}")
    Page<Payment> findByUserIsCurrentUser(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Then you need to pass the pageable object in from your service:

```
public Page<Payment> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("Request to get all Payments");
    Page<Payment> result = paymentRepository.findByUserIsCurrentUser(pageable);
    return result;
}
```

This will return a subset of results, based on whatever the `pageable` object contains. This includes size, page number, offset, and sorting. For example, a size of 20 and a page number of 0 will return the first 20 results. Changing the page number to 1 will return the next 20 results. These parameters are generally passed in from the front end to your API - you will notice that `getAllPayments()` in `PaymentResource` has a `Pageable` parameter.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much for your detailed help! I used the paginated solution.